# How to make show page date attribute view different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my show page `UserPrice` `:purchase_date` attribute that is a date_select and I want to change its view:

```
<%= @user_price.purchase_date  %>
```

from this (default):

**Purchase Date**: 2011-10-28

to these different formats:

1. October 28, 2011
2. 10/28/2011

How is this done?

Thank you.

Comment: there are many, many existing questions on SO about date formatting.  Please search on "ruby date format"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you might want put this in a helper (or these days, a decorator/presenter)... you could do the following directly in your view:

October 28, 2011

```
<%= @user_price.purchase_date.to_s(:long) %>
```

10/28/2011

```
<%= @user_price.purchase_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, for the precise answer!